# Adding hyperlink in mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, link-to, mailer

My requirement is to add a link to mail sent from application developed in Ruby On Rails. Clicking that link in mail need to route user to that particular record in the application.

Can someone please help me with this some sample code.

Comment: Use `_url` in the email template because _path gives absolute path

Comment: That's not true, `_path` gives you the relative path, e.g. `/books/1`, use for example `book_url(@book)`, this will give you `http://example.com/books/1`. Also consider reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for sending HTML emails, email templates...

Comment: Sorry my bad use _url

Answer (score 6):

In your view template use `_url`. E.g.:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_url(@user) %>
```

it will return the complete URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) method in the mail or you could use a simple [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag. The latter you would have to build up.

If you need information on how to build links and paths check the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). This has an example on the first section of the guide.

e.g. <%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %>

Besides this you need to provide more information if you want more help.

Comment: _path return relative path use _url it return absolute url.

Comment: @Sachin R 's comment is super useful because in the case that you want to send an email (without context to the site) but link something within the site, you will need to use the url, and not the path.  The difference is that the domain:port is not included in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with Ruby On Rails I would recommend looking at the videos on [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/).
For your email problem you can look at [sending-html-email](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email)

Also in the email I like to use the link_to helper like this

`<%= link_to 'Click Me', something_url(@user.id), %>`

I hope that this works. And Happy Coding

Comment: Why do you edit RoR to Ruby on Rails in the question and use ROR in your answer yourself?

Comment: For people who aren't familiar with the acronym RoR, it would be better to see 'Ruby on Rails' first (in the question) then they can make the association to RoR when they see it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks I will do this in the future

Comment: It's the other way around:
<% link_to 'Click me', something_url(@user.id) %>

Comment: @IvanRaszl Thanks, I just updated my answer to be the right way. Thanks for your update